# Is there anyway to add "or" when you want to edit data in the database?

Tags: c#, sql

```
    private void Update_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ////////////////////////////////////////// Update Data ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        string Query = "Update Contact_List set Id='" + Id_Box.Text + "' ,Name='" + Name_Box.Text + "' ,Adress1='" + Adress1_Box.Text + "',Adress2='" + Adress2_Box.Text + "' ,City='" + City_Box.Text + "' ,Province='" + Province_Box.Text + "' ,Postal_Code='" + Code_Box.Text + "' ,Phone='" + Phone_Box.Text + "' ,Email='" + Email_Box.Text + "' where id='" + Id_Box.Text  + "' ;";
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(Query, con);
        SqlCeDataReader reader;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Information Updated.....");

            while (reader.Read())
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        con.Close();
```

This code work, but the only problem is it only edit the data with the same Id in the textBox. So when I want to edit the persons Id then i can't because the new Id wasn't in the database so i cant edit it.

So is there anyway to have "or" in the query.

Algrithm : where id = id_box.Text or where name = name_box.Text in the query

so that i can change Id or Name

Comment: SQL INJECTION ALERT!!! DANGER!!!

Comment: use stored procedures

Comment: Why don't you check if it exists first, and take action depending on that logic? Hint: Lookup by Id, if there's any record(s), update, else add

Comment: The SQL injection alert is very relevant. However, have you tried `where id = $idBoxText OR name = $nameBoxText` with only one `where` keyword?

Comment: Your specifications are not complete: If id exists -> update the record. If id doesn't exist, but name -> update record and set new id? If neither of them exist -> insert?. What happens if id and name exist, but in different records?

Comment: for example :  if I  only have name : Leo Chan and Id : 123456 in the database  and i want to change my id  to 143246. i cant because the reader only look for the Id in the database that match 143246, if they can't find any 143246 in the database , it doesnt update. i have insert button, if they want to insert instead of update then they will click insert button and not the update

Answer (score 1):

**Use Parameterization**

You should NOT be using string-concatenation to build your queries as it can not only lead to nastiness like SQL Injection, but it can result in queries and parameters being passed in incorrectly.

A safer approach is to use SQL Parameterization, which passes each value in as a parameter to ensure that nothing bad gets through.

**Adding Additional WHERE Parameters**

With regards to appending certain properties to your WHERE clause, you could do so explicitly when building your query :

```
var query = "... WHERE Id = @Id OR Foo = @Bar";
```

or conditionally :

```
if(condition)
{
     query += " OR Property = @Property";
}
```

You'll just need to ensure that you are consistent and if you add another parameter in your WHERE clause that you add a matching value for the parameter prior to executing the query.

**Putting It All Together**

An example of these changes might look something like the following (with larger or repetitive sections omitted for brevity) :

```
private void Update_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Build your connection
    using(var connection = new SqlCeConnection("{your-connection-string}"))
    {
         // Build your query
         var query = "UPDATE Contact_List SET ID = @Id, Name = @Name, Adress1 = @Adress1, Adress2 = @Adress2, City = @City, Province = @Province, Postal_Code = @Postal_Code, Phone = @Phone, Email = @Email WHERE ID = @Id";

         // If you want to append another OR statement for your WHERE clause, you could
         // do so here
         if(condition)
         {
             query += " OR Property = @Property";
         }
         // Build your command to execute 
         using(var cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query,conn))
         {
              conn.Open();
              // Add all of your parameters
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id_Box.Text);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",Name_Box.Text);

              // Tons of others omitted for brevity

              // Check for your other WHERE condition property
              if(condition)
              {
                    // Add your parameter to match your clause
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Property","{your-value}");
              }
              // Do your thing here
              using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
              {
                    // Omitted for brevity
              }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: On top of this, I would recommend moving the SQL code to its own data abstraction class, as opposed to having it right in the button event handler.

Comment: I'm with you there, especially if it has to be used often (read as "more than once place"). I probably should have just left off the actual event handler code entirely to make the code sample not "tied" to that method.

Comment: Yes, you never want to have to wade through the code to find where Table X is referenced.